# discord.js client.users undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a blacklist command, and the command gives an error even though I tried many things.

- Discord.js version: `13.6.0`
- Node.js version: `16.13.2`

  **Command code:**

  ```js
  const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

  module.exports = {
      name: 'karaliste',
      description: 'kara',
      async execute(message, client, args) {
          const user = message.mentions.users.first() || await client.users.resolve(args.slice(1).join(' '));
          if (!user) return message.channel.send(`Karalisteye alınacak kişi belirt!`);

          if (user) {
              client.karalistedb.set(user.id, true);
              return message.channel.send(`\`${user.tag}\` Karalisteye alındı\nSebep: ${message.content.split(' ').slice(1)}`);
          }
      }
  };
  ```

  **Error:**

  ```js
  Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resolve')
  `
  ```

``

How do I fix this?

Comment: the error is saying that the users property on the client object is undefined, have you tried console logging the client object?

Comment: Could it be `async execute(message, args, client) {`?

Answer (score 0):

The properties of `client.users` are `cache` and `client`.

So, you would need to have the client search the cache for the user

```js
client.users.cache.resolve(args.slice(1).join(' '));
```